# DataTable search box and pagination under dc.js and datatables.net

Tags: datatables, dc.js

I'm using a `dc.js` **datatable** and I'd like to add a **search box** and a **pagination** by using [dataTables.net](https://datatables.net/) to filter data in my dataTable.

**What I have now ?**

In my **js** *file* I have this :

```
var datatable = $('#dc-data-table');
```

Then the *definition* of my datatable :

```
dc.dataTable('.dc-data-table')

        .dimension(Mydimension)

        .group(function(d) { 
               // some code;
                            })
        .size(dataSet.length)

        .columns([


            {
                label: '<B>'+'column1'+'</B>', 
                format: function (d) {
                    return // some code;
                }
            },
            {
                label: '<B>'+'column2'+'</B>',
                format: function (d) {
                    return // some code;
                }
            },
            {
                label: '<B>'+'column3'+'</B>', 
                format: function (d) {
                    return // some code;
                }
            },
            {
                label: '<B>'+'column4'+'</B>', 
                format: function (d) {
                    return // some code;
                }
            },
            {
                label: '<B>'+'column5'+'</B>', 
                format: function (d) {



                    return // some code;


                }
            },
            {
                label: '<B>'+'column6'+'</B>', 
                format: function (d) {
                    return // some code;
                }
            },
            {
                label: '<B>'+'column7'+'</B>', 
                format: function (d) {
                    return // some code;
                }
            },
            {
                label: '<B>'+'column8'+'</B>', 
                format: function (d) {
                    return // some code;
                }
            },
            {
                label: '<B>'+'column9'+'</B>', 
                format: function (d) 
            {              
                    return // some code;
                   }
           },

           {
                label: '<B>'+'column10'+'</B>', 
                format: function (d) {
                    return // some code;
                  }
                }

           ])


        .sortBy(function (d) {
            // some code;
        })

        .order(d3.ascending)

        .renderlet(function (table) {
            table.selectAll('.dc-table-group').classed('info', true);
        });
```

In my **Html** *file* I have this :

```
<table class="table table-hover dc-data-table"> </table>
```

And I have linked two **css** *files* `bootstrap.min.css` and `dc.css` :

**The result** :

[image]

**What I want :**

As you can see, I have many rows, I want to active **pagination** and have a **search box** to filter data like in [DataTables.net](http://www.datatables.net) examples.

Thank's in advance;

Comment: Would you please describe your code?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help.

Comment: @purvik7373 here is my code thank you in advance ;

Comment: Please who can help ??

Comment: I want take just the search box and the pagination from the [Datatables.net](http://datatables.net) . Who can help me to do that ... ?

Comment: No one to help here ?

Comment: @davidkonrad Thank you anyway, the question is how can I take just the search box and pagination from what is offered by Datatables.net ... Possible that I misspoke but my question were like that ... thank you again and sorry for my manner of demanding help ...